LSP suppresses `company-ispell` in LaTeX mode
I can't seem to get AUCTeX's LaTeX mode to do both complete words and use the LSP backend. My company-backends in LaTeX/PS buffer are
((:separate company-capf company-yasnippet)
 (:separate company-dabbrev company-yasnippet company-ispell))

company-ispell is there, I don't understand why it is not active. If I disable the LSP mode it works fine. The LSP is provided by lsp-mode, lsp-latex and texlab server. Without the LSP mode the backends are:
(company-reftex-labels company-reftex-citations
 (:separate company-dabbrev company-yasnippet company-ispell)
   company-capf)

The lsp-completion-provider is set to :capf. Can't it use LSP completion for anything that starts with a \ and company-ispell for the rest?
I have set the lsp-completion-provider to :none and just use the tab key to autocomplete LaTeX code.

Basically the LSP client doesn't know that anything not after \\ should be handled by another backend, so we only get the completions from LSP when using the default config. Hence the need for a custom approach like in one of the answers below.

Check the discussion in the following issue: https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/1611. It is probably very related.
If I understand correctly, the texlab server "has space as it trigger character, every new word will trigger completion and pass the prefix check." This makes it difficult to pass completions to downstream company backends.
Try setting company-capf as the last entry. This is my setup.
(setq company-backends
                                  '((company-files
                                     company-math-symbols-latex ; Math latex tags
                                     company-latex-commands
                                     ;; Math Unicode symbols and sub(super)scripts
                                     company-math-symbols-unicode
                                     company-ispell
                                     company-dict
                                     company-dabbrev
                                     company-capf)))


Thank you for the help.  Your setup didn't work for me. It worked only after adding :separate at the beginning, so that none of the backends filters out others. It works like I would like it too. Please see my answer.

;; FIXME: Fix company-ispell completion issue.
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'lsp)

(defun a2/latex-reset-company-backends-hook ()
  (when (derived-mode-p 'LaTeX-mode)
    (progn        
      (setq-local company-backends
                  '((:separate
                     company-reftex-labels
                     company-reftex-citations
                     company-math-symbols-latex
                     company-math-symbols-unicode
                     company-capf
                     company-latex-commands
                     company-dabbrev
                     company-abbrev
                     company-yasnippet
                     company-ispell))))))

(add-hook 'lsp-managed-mode-hook 'a2/latex-reset-company-backends-hook)
;; FIXME: END

This works fine for me. None of the candidates from one backend gets filtered out by other backends because of the :separate.
